# Spark java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when setting recursiveFileLookup to true, but not when false

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm trying to read in some json files from HDFS to spark streaming and then sending out an HTTP call

If I use the `recursiveFileLookup = true`, then the code works, but if I set it to `false` then the code doesn't work.

The schema seems to work fine. I'm really not sure what the issue is.

```
import spark.implicits._

val schema = new StructType()
     ...

val streaming_df = spark.readStream
      .schema(schema)
      .option("mode", "DROPMALFORMED")
      .option("maxFileAge", "90d")
      .option("maxFilesPerTrigger", 10)
      .option("recursiveFileLookup", false)
      .option("pathGlobFilter", "*.json.gz")
      .json(pathToJSONResource)

// scalastyle:off println
println("df is streaming:" + streaming_df.isStreaming)
println("df schema: " + streaming_df.printSchema)
// scalastyle:on println

val exploded_df = streaming_df
      .withColumn("messages", explode($"messages"))

exploded_df.writeStream
      .foreachBatch(batchHttpCall _)
      .outputMode(outputMode)
      .option("checkpointLocation", checkpointLocation)
      .start()
      .awaitTermination()
```

```
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 2 in stage 1.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 2.3 in stage 1.0 (TID 81) (ac3k9x2111.bdp.bdata.ai executor 2): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
```

|jsonPathResources looks like this

```
json-resource-path: "xxx/version=1.0.0/*"
```

with the folder schema looking like
`/version=1.0.0/year=2022/month=02/day=18/hour=17/json.gz`

Comment: If you specify the absolute path to the file (as opposed to glob) with the flag off does it work?

Comment: you can't specify an absolute path to the file. it returns "Option 'basePath' must be a directory". Removing everything but the file and adding a glob pattern at the end returns the same error

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you need to remove the glob pattern and just end with a `/`